# Как решить задачу без использования регулярных выражений?

Tags: c++, vector

Задан vector содержащий url. Например:

```
std::vector<std::string> url;
url.push_back("http://example.com/index.html");
url.push_back("https://example.com:8080/");
url.push_back("example.com");
```

Необходимо вывести на экран информацию о каждом url в формате 
Protocol: http Host: example.com Port: 80 Page: /index.html.
Если протокол не найден, то по умолчанию "http". Если порт не найден, то по умолчанию 80. Если страница не найдена, то по умолчанию /.

Регулярные выражения использовать нельзя, что окончательно меня запутало. Подозреваю, что find() может быть здесь полезен, однако не представляю как с помощью него "вычленить" соответствующие элементы в строках. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Обход строки циклом - думаю не запрещён.

Comment: Из полезных функций, можно использовать `strstr` и `strchr`

Comment: @nick_n_a но зачем предлагать сишные функции в плюсовом вопросе?

Comment: *не представляю как с помощью него "вычленить" соответствующие элементы в строках* А делай по шагам. Сперва ищи `://`. Нашёл? откусывай и пиши протокол, иначе пиши HTTP. В том, что осталось после откусывания, ищи `:`. Нашёл? То, что перед ним, суй в хост. Не нашёл? пиши порт 80. В остатке ищи первый `/`. И так далее... разрисуй всё деревоЮ учитывающее все варианты. А уж закодить его - дело плёвое.